# Проблема с терминалом

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

При составлении запроса в стандартном терминале творится что-то непонятное, строки начинают путаться, символы взаимозаменяться и пропадать. Проявляется это не сразу, некоторое время информация вводится корректно, исправить можно лишь тем, что свернуть и развернуть окно. Пробовал альтернативные терминалы, ситуация не изменилась. Может кто сталкивался с такой же проблемой?

Скриншот прилагается.

OC Kubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot

[image]

Comment: Вставляете откуда-то скопированный текст? Возможно попадает что-то, воспринимаемое терминалом как управляющие последовательности.

Comment: как только начинается подобное поведение:

     clear

PS: с Kubuntu дела не имел, лишь предпологаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, поймали привет библиотеки readline. Например, [этот](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2012-04/msg00001.html). У меня тоже бывает, особенно при копировании многострочного текста с кириллицей. К сожалению, костыли, исправляющие ситуацию, мне не известны. Можете поэкспериментировать с vi-режимом (по умолчанию, readline работает в emacs-режиме).

В любом случае, способ заполнения базы объемными данными вручную из консольного клиента - довольно неудобный, может, проще либо использовать пакетные возможности, либо наваять простенькую мордашку (GUI или Web).